# AHK | prevent resetting Hotstring count after "spaceless" hotstrings

Tags: autohotkey

I use some hotstrings either with :o: option or with manually sending a {bs} for other purposes.
In Both cases, if the string i want to add to the end of the previous hotstring happens to be aslo a hotstring in itself, it Will trigger the hotstring!
How to prevent this?
Example:
`:o:ahk::AutoHotKey`
=> ahk+space+ahk should be: "AutoHotKeyahk", but instead it gets: "AutoHotKeyAutoHotKey"
Note: IF the text behind was not a hotkey it does not trigger again ofcourse.
AutoHotkey+ahk => AutoHotkeyahk
Also in general it would be nice to know, how to make hotstrings more aware if some letters are physically behind the cursor even though for various reasons it is not registered properly in the keycount -ergo prevent malfires of hotkeys in improper context.

Answer (score 0):

So I have tried hard with various approaches and ran into several errors/bugs.
Finally I have a method that works reliably under all tested circumstances.
Ill post the code... feel free to post a better/more elegant one if you have.

```
IsModifier:=1
#inputlevel 1
SendLevel 1
LAlt & space up::
{
        SendInput,{space}
        sleep 50
        SendInput,{bs}
        IsModifier:=0
        Loop
        {
            Sleep,10
            if (GetKeystate("Enter") = 1) or (GetKeystate("?") = 1) or (GetKeystate(".") = 1) or (GetKeystate("Space") = 1)
            {
                break
            }
        }
        IsModifier:=1
return
}
#if (Ismodifier=1)
#inputlevel 0
#Include GeneralHotStrings.AHK
```